# How to read FormData in NextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js, multipartform-data

I'd like to read fetch's body. Here's what I send:

```js
fetch('/api/foo', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new FormData(formRef.current),
});
```

[image]

And now I only need to parse the body. But I don't know how. I can't use `FormData` on the server side, because it says `ReferenceError: FormData is not defined`. And I can't also use `forEach` like on the client.

What should I do?

```js
export default function sendMail(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): void {
    // console.log(req.body instanceof FormData);
    // req.body.forEach(console.log);
    console.log(req.body['name']);
    res.status(200).json({});
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [POST multipart/form-data to Serverless Next.js API (running on Vercel / Now.sh)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62411430/post-multipart-form-data-to-serverless-next-js-api-running-on-vercel-now-sh)

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 17):

You could use **formidable**.

```
npm install formidable
```

Then in your code use

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { Formidable } from "formidable";

//set bodyparser
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false
  }
}

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const form = new Formidable();

    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) reject({ err })
      resolve({ err, fields, files })
    }) 
  })

  //return the data back or just do whatever you want with it
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'ok',
    data
  })
}
```

Comment: Disabling the body parser is required. This was the missing piece for me! Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to create a new instance of `formidable`. just call `formidable()` and pass its result to `form`. Other than that, this worked perfectly.