# Next.JS how to parse multipart/formdata data in req sent from the React front end to the Node Backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, http, next.js

So when I send a multipart type data from my front end (react because I am using Next) to the Node backend, I get the data. I need a way to parse it. I have seen Multer, but all of the tutorials show this code:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

app.post('/applyForJob', upload.array('files'), uploadFiles);

function uploadFiles(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.files);
  res.json({ message: 'Successfully uploaded files' });
}
```

I get this code and would love to implement it. But I can not access 'app.post' on my Next API route. I can override the default server and write my own node server, but then I can not deploy to Vercel, which I planned on doing.

So I need to parse and access multipart data in the API route. The data is a couple of text inputs and up to two file inputs. I have been searching all over for an answer and have found nothing yet. So any help would be appreciated.

I will post the req.body to show I am receiving it, I just need to parse and access it. (it looks nasty though lol):

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryRd0FO6fKwoKf2ui6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="firstName"

Lawrence
------WebKitFormBoundaryRd0FO6fKwoKf2ui6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lastName"

Mueller
------WebKitFormBoundaryRd0FO6fKwoKf2ui6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

lawrencemueller18@gmail.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryRd0FO6fKwoKf2ui6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="phone"

16266786830
------WebKitFormBoundaryRd0FO6fKwoKf2ui6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="resume"; filename="LawrenceMuellerResume2022.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.7
%����
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-US) /StructTreeRoot 26 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 170 0 R/ViewerPreferences 171 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[ 3 0 R] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</ExtGState<</GS5 5 0 R/GS8 8 0 R>>/Font<</F1 6 0 R/F2 9 0 R/F3 14 0 R/F4 19 0 R/F5 21 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 612 792] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 5734>>
stream
x��=�r���?�#9�*§�☻j�C1�|��}k�7�g▲d����$�(������ź�UEy§!▲u�D▲�Lp��������.����û�����,�s�����O~|]�==��>������p��♫☼�X��-o☼♫��'�پ⌂��+������W�▼§9Q*+rJ�E���∟♫feEs����UV��g��Ǐ>����)���x_�⌂§���:�Ɋ���[v������G��H♠'N>=~D�"#��yAy&����§�☻x��2�d�▼?�s������|��)<���Gip�,bM" >[☻(γ↕�♂����J�♂�%*u�☺����Qxu�ۓ��ܕ*�ࢲ��0.xN�~�˲  �~+��n♀�j��H�s�ɢ�l� ↔�����ۿ���(g���;��٭y[����maޖ��↓K#e♫�☼$�+.��2���yexw☼oܳ��9��q�vr�9/rE���▲ɥ-�� ��I=���س�b�R%¶d^�Y�ʼ�[‼�~�ǘ▲♠��♣
o��☺�oW�F�Ky♂_♠♥��;V�;�ȼ�
�~�[�♦��UH♠��P����
▲��L�qD3♣��CD�G�)�+���S_�:��_�♠��Ŝ���ɜE����E��nGD�j�↓���§�↕1►▬����Ü��¶�X�K→0D�6�6��♂♠XV�4&��Lf���'ko�߭Q��,0☼§�@�(�b��&�z�I♫c��♦`<♦r�ʕ� |1�S���▲�↨"g_�����}߿|�♂���/s�
�Wq�*�ôѽa�r:j+�j*§?���"S0t�h��y0�ʟ'��4���▬z%∟��{بR6�pL♀=�)�K☼�p��-¶�▬   <��C(AѲz���
����!'ߺ♣�#~�ƹ�→Y�↨�     StȎ\�%YY��♫☺↕K �♦JQu�
{2UG��a��↑
~/�Ye^0�*m��a�IHgl☼��T!8O�↓��c㡾�7)g�ͷ��M◄w��\�◄�b0�{�$�☼x♥���9��9����]�a2J�4nT?%i�g♣���d EW�Eo♫!\◄mNĞ��.�=J♥����͉↓]��\☻Ƿ�n0�.ӣ7'��§����►��q◄�p����
�v��p
♫:���↓�D�↨eh����x&�6��m���a�&d�ˎ��kQ�'E���▲�ϢZ⌂f偄7^�aq�W��c���_�K
���3!��A'n�☻�▲+a@☻h�ރc��k♥▼�.Ƿ�]�3
<+�►�m�1☻Nx�☼♀�#\���Rrz&3Z��↓ ���/p��Y>9sK���⌂ ��z♣���↨∟7§↑[����|☼�]�‼�\n���e7�∟�♠◄∟�▬☺n▬��g-a0{�z1���☻∟J▬�|b�Uh�&@�8�z�ɼ�!`�Z�.WS��c���,���Cq¶�kp7♥�^��J♀�↓�♀��s���>9���P�%��n,JT���ܫ���@�_��gx6��D�*���4�"<sZ4�#x��     
        /z=@|��C�"�Z�Q�q�&V�►�♠5�ē���~HwΞ_޽�§��ǉ�
���f$F☻��{_�{���♣�K�Σ��:P�c☼]�㱋f�D!!���_V�h�?CXv�m∟t<~‼♀bP��r�S̕��‼�2��y;6o��� �L¶�����Ff��r0☻����↕��mdk���>끒E$�E԰���!�j☻♀�}qh��{���hP�♀b{%�☻↑��h�TQp���l▬�☻�2qiϬ���~�rԢ�e�ج�E{�/☺9�Z��ҩ��%��6Kko͛=���2g☼�6�v���i`�m↑��-
�`�▼���`¶���
����q�%�>�‼���♦���E��↓��!!B☻���슷�c �F�"3-=�����v��♦�p�ʃ�/�ڣB˽���U�-��§ú↕G♫∟�Ѯ�ߔ�N����h�TG��!�>uY�K�����ʼ�☼��→�W�9���&�zj�ĦH[∟qpK���^�'�♫�ӝ)�♦�=        �|�v�_ub��/��!
�↕�O�G♦�`♂D�J�p؛▲▲їnF��▲<��e§☻��9-O���_���1O�v=ٍ�`Y��=G�C0�qV��♫�P�X�
y��♥�¶��*☺y��v�↕�I
�Ѽ☻↔�f��9֎0P����a��@♥aR��_?�ʙ▲�R�~↕H~$↨��↑bx���uM∟��29F (b��r�▬k�▬�↨∟O
"v��
��W�p?g♣Z▬↑��zX�暐z∟��♣�qjl��5�ql���j�.V)\�\�.��K�↑�.♣5W!Ps♫���▬5��o��2:�/�T��M�y�♫�-t���*��3֎�‼7y☼�6@�R�↑���st�¶:wjv�◄^��-�R   �→����݉�♣��☼�
�(�@◄↨fH�̍eNU��`�(���*¶�♦�W�8♦`��q S��♦��j;Nt�∟▼$���T�{♦�p/�M5��I|��#�?挘H����‼����7♀<|��19��N0�♀FE��Q�E{����§��3��▼♂� S0�G-�q�NvѧD���▲ǜΡN�peRB\���;m�r�E�53T��∟�cļ�[�<���e�G▬±��U8�☻{f�Ĕ�\�A�)�q☼*�t�♫‼♫%}�(♫���↓|�y�ù8▲
��>�↕�(T�
Vw�vj�7B��)3Ƶ�s]�U��↔♂z ���‼��ͱ^���     �↔݃�x9G-35���♦����bi�O�6V��¶�Oh oу���f♣il��▲9���Ԩ1�PL�69G↑���M↑r�}��֣C�nu�X��\���
ϡ˱ZZ�e�↓��˙}�~�y�♀^��GrY▼�S���^s=։��J�0�        ���!⌂m  �ȿ�☼'������↨/=���♥��C7d▼;��R�ѝ^v►^
�K∟�o��aq����GpjT��-%p�♣˂2'F�u�|���vj�8+r^m90]�ZNn_��)�↓�5
��׺j����?݅����F�♦6g�C��r�мgE��)��umk�3�� ,PK�Xe8c[�G�ַ���²Đ'�r7�1Z{��$�>:N}wv��cuo��Wk↕o��z���→n�M→♂��YGx▲V{���;���1����r7#��N�@-����→��◄‼�S�∟��;و���♂R*\_�=Y~�??���♫¶�.▲�♣����        ��q�n�j�x�����:����P�.�↔��$�֭��gh-
{�ON��P�L��x-Nw◄�r.�♠♀☼<�↑@a�%♫��K\ê☻S▼�����s���lA����H�i♀�zѺ‼f�8�]4�♂�u_j���c,��;���.☻yNdN�¶yI♂���0LB��0qȻ��8�ï�J�LNT�w����)4��iJ�I▼��J�C��������
�↑��U:.�^�)��4l'pZ��{�3�e۱f��W�;�C��d��♣♫�♫R/Z� ��7�{
∟���� �1lyڶ��6~�1�▲�q�,��?�r� ��`��֤���♀�:e�x�V♥ljI7���=�→↑j���k_s<U�� ��ޏ♠B☼���P^7+tg`���♦�����vU6������(�P�P♠�t↔5�v���&�7���%~�t�����▬+*��� �p�]�►n�V☼���F��p�i�����t♦I���♣�M��Z�Y�wwƊߜ�☺�<�վ�I¶i�`����♠���+��(♣JG�-���▲
ֵJ�Y�w�rږ�?►��}�v1��2?☼]����-�Na<冴��I▼G♂��FO!ZȜ��∟[→�C{�+T�m]�
K��L�♥�}vվ�∟�►"�o�е)q��E�→x ↔�♠r��#5&�eΩ�9&���������=▼9*J�\��y♂��♣�7�ç���♦∟�@�↓�8ԎUs��T�⌂��'▲�↕̳H��∟�VK↨��Z��`Dl���sd�XH�~�`bZ↔]�#�$�↕���=���b$¶"�_3�(�♀j%�_�u�Ai%'��2Tj�w▬)܂];C���*e
j��e3����→♣��7IxR�ZƑ�B�$���Mm∟qi���Ĵ�#�<ˆĔ�[GN�
↕��5�;~�Ź�&���
�z�a�☼�T���,z�}����+Tb7↑n��J☺�zw헺♂�↨��p��▲�3����\�=‼�Z��=-�����=��{ߺq��=B♂�◄�$♠���cw�vJK6�#���`�♦Uu,�!♥Bi�8��▲��%��*���X-Һn�§c��J��f)�e=☼�☼⌂r�}tYh��NB��}�_��∟_^�r�|bFq�#[♫OWN;       �r�?EN��w&�q��&S�օ!�B����1�?6j�\b��→*�∟,�p�?8k↑a�x���fS����↕���S�!�↑n�↔⌂�s�L↔K3��ۆ♂�♫��7��x�c�Y��� ▲V���w&�q�O��h���kMx�4=�p����~����n�q(���♦�a5�)�kt�h��t�N��♣�☺�V#�◄uٳe�8Q�<�ĲKQ�☻ޙ�ǡ▲����FY�↨�ZW
�֓m0!→�k��v♂aGO�◄�o��i���0,q�h���o�Fu1�R/U^����%��-�X+P��V�☼j♣��wf♣�P7sxN��*�᪘�I�|r>�NL►��@%�d♫�*s�☻������♫��"I���,ß?�♥���^�\˘♂�▬�▲�zI���82���F�鼛▼;�}�↕�◄l�fW��s_z�t{̩�KW����)�]/�攭��♂�$ÉN☼�k�k�պ��q�↨�→g���6�F1�x��ߘ���
��bX�ړ��A�<5�,��$N�;�p��)�I�کH∟iR       �����w&�q�/�[u������]����f�     ϝzH�:��n��"֢Y��Ak��→���]*�����♀���cO��;��?�{�_X�55�吏b�҅�q�'���)JSP�‼{P♠76���*ӟ0���w6��P☼↨↨6+��fcf���h�
4�����ź��mdfΝ☻���>߁��p��)▲���c��Y
�☼w��↨�M�2uމ�Ʋ☼,����♂cQ���`ع��S/:O�� l�Y05��3�LA�9Ļ��Lo▬▲☻�n��W�Ö2O��3♫9p;�"�w�§�S8L▲♥�-W↕@�J�↔Y#��EK���♦�▼���¶;;↕P'���^�z�◄�N��H�{i۱���♀�☼�y9���'x9Q�;Suq��Bk↕z.6#���3�↨^h⌂8��Y�q�*~�d�p♫
�gn���=Is��◄.�i]↔��ں���M��]→(0�E��y����%⌂'G♥fl☻�X{m���↕����*�8RIm2����C&3�?#1�  I♫*X�d�¶ĳE���6��S\������↓0�ò��#�U0���↔��e�Mv��↕⌂f�p�8�♥��4��0��\��z��5�c���X#mW��§7�/�~�fد�i[�ӏF�-z
7+�5�►`R蟡�ݜO♀��!)♥��♂����♫�(f�Վ♥ޕ�O@=�G        +o�\F�/5�O{s�m��o�a�'☻����ƫ▼>��k?]�P��◄X4����������Y¶u;��=§?Z�O��턻��E���E��Q�I↔��vQC���`�↕ئ�����J0̅<�L��ݕ�ā�^‼��=i:���↓��4��N�i�%���ܦ��ܪ�J#�����^���RP/1Ե�Z�\�;���♂ȏC�GM)
�N▬�2?�0d�}}→3�V>�ko�W☺�EV«�d�  �D��.r~ӡ���?{�{�
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type/ExtGState/BM/Normal/ca 1>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/TrueType/Name/F1/BaseFont/ArialMT/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FontDescriptor 7 0 R/FirstChar 32/LastChar 122/Widths 162 0 R>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Type/FontDescriptor/FontName/ArialMT/Flags 32/ItalicAngle 0/Ascent 905/Descent -210/CapHeight 728/AvgWidth 441/MaxWidth 2665/FontWeight 400/XHeight 250/Leading 33/StemV 44/FontBBox[ -665 -210 2000 728] >>
endobj
8 0 obj
<</Type/ExtGState/BM/Normal/CA 1>>
endobj
9 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type0/BaseFont/ArialMT/Encoding/Identity-H/DescendantFonts 10 0 R/ToUnicode 159 0 R>>
endobj
10 0 obj
[ 11 0 R]
endobj
11 0 obj
<</BaseFont/ArialMT/Subtype/CIDFontType2/Type/Font/CIDToGIDMap/Identity/DW 1000/CIDSystemInfo 12 0 R/FontDescriptor 13 0 R/W 161 0 R>>
endobj
12 0 obj
<</Ordering(Identity) /Registry(Adobe) /Supplement 0>>
endobj
13 0 obj
<</Type/FontDescriptor/FontName/ArialMT/Flags 32/ItalicAngle 0/Ascent 905/Descent -210/CapHeight 728/AvgWidth 441/MaxWidth 2665/FontWeight 400/XHeight 250/Leading 33/StemV 44/FontBBox[ -665 -210 2000 728] /FontFile2 160 0 R>>
endobj
14 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type0/BaseFont/SymbolMT/Encoding/Identity-H/DescendantFonts 15 0 R/ToUnicode 163 0 R>>
endobj
15 0 obj
[ 16 0 R]
endobj
16 0 obj
<</BaseFont/SymbolMT/Subtype/CIDFontType2/Type/Font/CIDToGIDMap/Identity/DW 1000/CIDSystemInfo 17 0 R/FontDescriptor 18 0 R/W 165 0 R>>
endobj
17 0 obj
<</Ordering(Identity) /Registry(Adobe) /Supplement 0>>
endobj
18 0 obj
<</Type/FontDescriptor/FontName/SymbolMT/Flags 32/ItalicAngle 0/Ascent 1005/Descent -216/CapHeight 693/AvgWidth 600/MaxWidth 1113/FontWeight 400/XHeight 250/StemV 60/FontBBox[ 0 -216 1113 693] /FontFile2 164 0 R>>
endobj
19 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/TrueType/Name/F4/BaseFont/Arial-ItalicMT/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FontDescriptor 20 0 R/FirstChar 32/LastChar 118/Widths 169 0 R>>
endobj
20 0 obj
<</Type/FontDescriptor/FontName/Arial-ItalicMT/Flags 32/ItalicAngle -12/Ascent 905/Descent -208/CapHeight 728/AvgWidth 441/MaxWidth 1876/FontWeight 400/XHeight 250/Leading 33/StemV 44/FontBBox[ -517 -208 1359 728] >>  
endobj
21 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type0/BaseFont/Arial-ItalicMT/Encoding/Identity-H/DescendantFonts 22 0 R/ToUnicode 166 0 R>>
endobj
22 0 obj
[ 23 0 R]
endobj
23 0 obj
<</BaseFont/Arial-ItalicMT/Subtype/CIDFontType2/Type/Font/CIDToGIDMap/Identity/DW 1000/CIDSystemInfo 24 0 R/FontDescriptor 25 0 R/W 168 0 R>>
endobj
24 0 obj
<</Ordering(Identity) /Registry(Adobe) /Supplement 0>>
endobj
25 0 obj
<</Type/FontDescriptor/FontName/Arial-ItalicMT/Flags 32/ItalicAngle -12/Ascent 905/Descent -208/CapHeight 728/AvgWidth 441/MaxWidth 1876/FontWeight 400/XHeight 250/Leading 33/StemV 44/FontBBox[ -517 -208 1359 728] /FontFile2 167 0 R>>
endobj
37 0 obj
<</Type/ObjStm/N 126/First 1042/Filter/FlateDecode/Length 1911>>
stream
�X�g����9�<��A��4Q�Z,o�v→Ҡ��K�J{� ↔¶�♠��♠h�<�▼�`�zi?�K�)��↓�Y�!☼Cf�<<→=`∟�6►`Q9�z���B�I,��♀�ͥA↓g�J�ﰽ♦~O;�ʄ!�♦�&↑�D�¶*¤xMP2a������P*��▲¶���Vú9��O��H���+�‼(6��Zg`b���g$
�4�b�#���q�◄�3���H��♥y▬;�'���▲
�C��㗐Gqbف§K�→���►∟∟�♂b�#�·��U��☺▼Z"♦�@p♀{�`�►i;→�3\D♂g��↕���H�‼��&X0→�8�-▬4�P☼��f1��0G♀xy�buB�`P���������qu���_��܌������G�N���Y/_>⌂�♦&�Pd��t���e)?�R�☻◄���⌂*�*��♣��K��▬ޙ���♠�$♣q�ڞ35��m��mY�EYUS8ߒ§��
U��f�A�����aÉ�D�6vBqG�B(�!�↕N♀��FQ��(6s�◄�#,V]��a�l1☺k&�lZ6ns<5oĦ��↑�m)T�/�K,�Tt�TϪ��♫JH#Ff��n§↕[�‼T���j�e�
�☼⌂l.⌂��◄ş�:�☼�ē�Z@̪~X�R��[Z��E:{�MG♀�6��K��֮♦���t�ۓR��↕♦�
�¶���   ��#�"��⌂�X↔���\�Mv]�"►{☻��CW�X��♦V�{N]�b��♦V���w���k�R\�♫`���mX�y.���
4)�♦`���f�ӏ�#D�!�}◄׾�►�EH�sHW�Ss����� ���CT��♀;��!j�►�‼���r�rL�����^♣��26O��T�}A2����-Xn�q��/sS�?U��}D���`��f¶�^ei����9�☼∟b�6�������v��U:0���ă���q<�lv�����q�]�Qv��bM�U�D��%��������Ki^�-ֺ����'�������∟S�l~��Ƌ݊�����L<�� 
���4��WwXa������vw��→☼���7�o_6�o☼V��▼_�qGJ�V▼�↨�����_�������fsu0pvs}9▲�-r0�j��]����ߎ��O��?�c�t�O���������☺��;�D���▼♠��↔⌂�☼T3)��↓�eʣo♥s♂���>�|HJ#���S������="�◄  ����FQ������혃v����☺�Gt*�y�\�▼���e�qy⌂T��V�▼������k�☺=ʈ���h�s*☻⌂ϔ�☻.;�R`:��♀���‼�∟�ϟ�YX�
endstream
endobj
82 0 obj
<</O/List/ListNumbering/Disc>>
endobj
91 0 obj
<</O/List/ListNumbering/Disc>>
endobj
128 0 obj
<</O/List/ListNumbering/Disc>>
endobj
140 0 obj
<</O/List/ListNumbering/Disc>>
endobj
152 0 obj
<</O/List/ListNumbering/Disc>>
endobj
158 0 obj
<</Producer(��Microsoft� Word for Microsoft 365) /Creator(��Microsoft� Word for Microsoft 365) /CreationDate(D:20220224164934-08'00') /ModDate(D:20220224164934-08'00') >>
endobj
159 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 364>>
stream
x�}S�n�0►��§>�0�P       !%��8���~��¶�↑ː♥⌂_ۛ�¶K`�=3;6�_��R�#�?t�+↑I�J�a菚♥�á�^�↕���ܛw��|#��a���M�e↓�?��0�,֢�Ó�k☺����.*���R�Ё∟I��9◄�↑��Z��↔►�ɖ�0��8-�����¶►�p�ax/`P5]�♥xY`FN��↓�R��T����ڱ#�♫☻→8�i�̺�n∟-(���ظOg�;�§�Ea���q ʐ�
↓�U��!�+�c\D���$��‼�� 4��i7ԡ�!J►��}a���t����7���l��↕ο��U��☼>☻��
endstream
endobj
160 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 49798/Length1 107452>>
stream
x��}{|Tյ����3��$3!�↓2g2d►$Dr☻   �◄      ►b♠�$� O☺�☼¶5�☼����
Z��☼N▲��h�b���§k�����z��~,Z����L"X{?��O��wg����^{���^{�Ǚ0�↑◄%#�iݤ�♣�i‼n�!bs!mhZԸ��"mDcV►�O��^�>����D�↨►������E#~�◄$��~�~���sR�?�J�¶!z�vns�����}↓m}
[G↨�Ԣ�;�~▼���]���׎§4"�["�s��FǓ�lbC�D���→�]�9��G9�#uQ�Fi��Hl�▬a�§���������%→ѠqK▬�,����(_#��\ټ���?!��Ed/ 1V3Q���☺3SJ�nq[H�����/�▲���mg.w�e2�VC_�yt��4�I_n��:'���!y����Vr�►���jt��~9J%i
Y��J◄→pǨ�;��S-
O2�\�|�♠E�ѵ�→▬j&�Uі���r�k2+2�f�→�h4�I♂(��H)�¶7������@��w�J+♦��Kh+�堻D]���☺�K�����l"�◄8U䡻�ڷxi�R���z�♣�♥|►������TB��⌂♦u�ʘ
���֛��♠�▼@y‼d☼��!�►�↓�78�[�wQ��@‼����⌂☺h�B�m�→t∟�
}�☻↔♥\�^�5���(�[��j!→��*���^▼�n☺�♥;L�)@▼�⌂���$�i�☼m��♣˷��a�]%�         [0����l+}�o�g+-f♥}��‼��♦$ ☺     H��\`[��~h/(��=�& ☺     H�☼     ���,@'%��♦$ ☺   H@☻↕��♦$ ☺      H@☻↕��♦$ ☺      H@☻↕��♦��@~��|�\�;���-  H��▬`♂↕��♦����ki��Ű��L|�I^�☺|�1-♫r♂͐R�L��♂�qt>�C��/�@�侐��R-�→��))�F����B��U7B�����W]OӔ��|�05)_У�♂�Q�$N��rz�TB
J☺�h♥��6H-�O�H{��cm�?♣↔��Eq�'�▬х�‼z⌂�▼�s�b
Q.ڲ�♂����!��?♣���▼چ♦��o�����♣̌�♠☺'�♥��yA�~h��⌂���o����'☺        H@☻↕�@��'��♂��!�&��↑♦���K�↓ڏF�tZB��fz�:h'��&M��ij���▬�§�↕uy^z���o#��y4�4j�+�:���βX���g=M�&→Mã�X��ž��땣☼▲������r��㧉�y���W �[�⌂�=�W�{�g'�K~6�↓�5}�$↑�↑��j �
Ȋ�&ىR���^i�↓�Y�9nOoC��▼�{^���☺♥§♀▲RX4t���◄%#G��▼k��r��♂&\Xu�ċ'UO�2���^R↨�~���o����J1�♫�!���Z��"y+����i��U�Z�\�d�§�▬.�?o��s�g��]R;�f���Z���KG�,↓Q<lhQ��♣�♠��w^�@~▼⌂�O�����s��23��z���)�♫{��j1�¶Y�♠T��5�z�A�♥�♂.↑(��→�↕4�*D�∟���M�Y:���)AC��→�覱���F�'FCw�m♥���8iVC�>�?�qF�.5�D▼� ���3�;��M▬����[}v�[��►▬�R~e�l�zr]e���♂
Wf�SE6∟^��'ם]�‼i(�6P���C�wUSU��W��t�
���}z��▼j��Qx��lM�>�d��6�+�ض�8cw��4��↓��.��)=�e�"�♦♦��6���Ώ1�►I�
|�7#�6��c4�}#��↑☺b��◄g�!cc↕q~I����US◄���6�m;�X§§u��g������������→Jm4�‼M�k�BS�Z{d�\���►��쾚���8�i�5��4�f����N�[kj��9�c����n���
OG<��ޢ�↔�&{BF♂�d�a�n]�1�3♫�&�ux�戵��M♫ۤ��6~qР̠�♂����!►��0L�O�↔↕Z~�hD��K%v��8H����Q�9▬�ŖoX����ܞ�8����☼�m‼↑��d}�|��0¶�Qi¶c♫cm�¶♂|�Qy��♠∟;��֦F���fB�▼�♂!P�f�<(♫갸955���r�'���9MbO`آА↑��Z�6��♠�!l2��Vu♣T��듿Q��Tc�i♀OE]↕������
�46��檋x�y_�(�:�Z��;∟�#�`b�8(���n
Q�▬���j��F��♦Q��=a�j���☼�{[>[S}�N8CO��r�↔�V��<I→ ▲�G��+♣��T‼�^Tǩ�T7���‼&�\
↓→‼☼→‼�}�hj~a��6G��♀)♥�̀�K�2�∟�0F^�,��♫�).ѤԎ>��M{%���%F��'�v����ƣ�$��♦?▲+��;�]���/���6�^�����.⌂�n�G�ϑ�☺7☺�☻☼☺O☻M�(�#x���P����
&X►g��q&�↔gR3�g�N�����F�oC�m��m�N�'♀�OHS�[���o�����%�;
��W��M�▼j☼��g�W�♂��@�����▼�5���y���⌂c�↨AsA☼���s�T��rB↔'�‼��
⌂��O�7Z��{�;/�☻`↓p↕p&p-�������T4��♫������/♠}�▲��6߫♣�"U�♦F�☼♫�&uS�k���#+�����‼I��;��$p�Jp"       ,�→�H☻��‼I`�Lp" L�☺�$�▼|�O_o�♣L-O���K��K��Kא̯◄☼�C▬����⌂⌂xl�▬���ۊ��▲�:��>�Z�Y덬u%k-e���� k���\֪���l♦\�ʴ�s�%Z▬k=�Z�b�-�5�Z�Y
k▼֪�b-�}�‼�♀Ri��r��@�▼��'���Q▼bއ=a/�C���Ӡ��Ŕ�s♣���_▬�☼→Y�↑�g?*��4�#@↓‼�▼a�▼��G♥)Hˀ3���'�Q�      �y0|��� -�☺g☻o☻�♦�♀sN☻9-����0L↑]►7|↕P������q����q♠�↨Hk=,%�Mʍ��b���{V���0ǎ�↔_|� k����׊����ӵ�����6�v{���}�+#�X    ♣X>j1���c◄
t(y�‼���ZTKi☼♀��bɢ�♫�?<Ǽ⌂�D8؏=��⌂P#2k��▲�'vx_���}� b�dO �@v���N�S♀Օ(���Q�↔��♂<FAs��▬�¶��t�♣h��3˫���↔�2�e�Ҙ�0Qg�w0���0����ԟ♂I�wشi�◄6W^o�3O2☼7↨��}f����mN��Z��d��b�X,&�l�▬��E�G���2��¶D��SF��;�H�g�b�c▬N↨��K��USǰ*}_‼U�R��S◄fË��▼�p�RU�↑}D�*b�Nы�U���Һ6��♫A��5xu�����►�r��Xv↕c�Uw�♣=o�]�►ee\]�U�:�U2��;��x→�♠���{���WM�k▼�uk�1!���Q�U���G1;��ةʊ�쯂��vJ���*�4�"¶���ZC�T�W�!t�j�YpJ♂=R-�1��1�|ԇ^▼A�g�R���o�→z2‼zm-}*+���1t2Uj1tZ2ճu♫�C'?���h�♥�΁�V���6T▲��z♀§�C▲C��r♀��oT
������n�$�ot<1↔��n↔�Q�♦�/4�     ♠YǨP�♀�1V���↓ؠ�q��,q#WۚB�Ϸ☻
,▼X.���DQ���2^�u�(�{↨�↕/rB��ಫZ����y§��▬Dˮ↕♫����⌂♣(�ԵƊ�eDUz��Uz↓^~��fH��ݲ���Ht_LB(I=�BV*dVk\����8↔+VA+����\��ZB��[Uñ#��?¶څ��8+ZB↑`♂♂���6�f�¶˓↑s7.�*��}�,Nc5Q���%= �§���2�YÝ�↓u���p���qw▲♀:►t h!h�T��♠�↕/�Z-��$[��l��v�→   
�����9�c�-(�(�◄�cA��E?▬��O�kF�H���b��)�K�f�Pk�N↕��
t���J��→��$VK��Q�n+�B�z‼v�↓��v`u��>P.M�$♂�s◄�b→v��x6`��◄A��/�.�c�㹑��▲f[��‼����c⌂���w�§Ǳ�M܍���Q�������▼����?���2�<��♫�J���↑V�����.�+�ȇ�(�\��W6)[�'�_+�Lv�͸0������?�N↨u��Z����↓}��1'��t§↔�m��$�?ğ�&ʧ�)l.V�
u�jx�.W�↓v↔"���)4=�(�▼�����C♥�▼���@�[�♥ZK[ت��i�ך�N��ھH↓�☼)�♥y��ɧ����/��ϲ�‼<O#3Z�Ma�☼4�ʢwF⌂��>☼;��4♂��c↑��/f[�/԰B�p�����.�m�q�↕�M�>▬�2.�I��~aV��∟�∟��5��zj�S�ˤ�y��ZxA��◄Wa��]^*�"���Ě_��f3��V��N�⌂]►▼�c3Tį��4���c&s�߯�"E>&�
�,▼c�m1)Ǹ�AfŖ3����ӥgJ/v~V:�L)��w~�d�`����G�K>}�J���¶��Ty��W     :|�▬g�BVZ��
+J����П▼b♂%+������]�▲<�1\&u�k�1$я�↑���↨↔y�C�H�♂-/�oh�Ɇ��K����NX-▬I�d���R��Vn�MGKw�♀���$��3��→ʲ�K▼�↕��G�g����c��gJ�0WjI��!�Y0���L6�H1�5+6�s�%�`�Td��
☼♫�� ♫�y�T�_b�x�Z�5�7(��I↨�1h��)x!K5[�+�M�▬P�eޔ|↓INI�$�I���¶‼_⌂��q���0�♀‼���↔�bf�♦t�☻�5�xxq�Ɍ'��ؑ��2q�������☼�`��=�♂�|�3_�→
�↨�))♠s���0�O�¶��OKI�&��'S�V�+�?Y�R�ݖ��kh����̌t'?�↕��;��u+�L�x�k2;��ݳs}x�k_�y�D�ߺ,��]�[pw��la�v▬‼��☻Fp2�!��I��↨c�ڜ$☻▬���1�q�1��¶�{渘n��v���ߚe!>♂♫��"�k���w���↔�/),↓.↔<������KaM9���|◄V���↨���%↕��&�►?�∟e        ���%w�X;V�
��
&▲▼2���↓���↨♣9��^�|��▼�lߎ
�0��↑�D�F�Y\♀�46�m$o��f�↑���z�↨M·݆���u►♂H��G?�%�i)汝$E�iO+��;��Vr�ĸ�I�&q�jbi�41�ڤ��⌂x|;v���W�����l�V♠♣�op>'f§��♥�T����"�▲_�U��|�e→▬˴�G�KهH�ͺ�]��~���++i�♫G&���FT        F�▬aeu�]H(�nGj↨2*@H↔Dr►#6�∟���m�3�d↕-}��4�‼ZvR�I4↕
6��"§��&�iS�X6��k�֤���X�IY���E�↨f�u����>#{�{�yARS���♂���5����KYm�`^�|1�-��鍤?����T�~Fv�czj)3�7�cIq�♂��↔L�\��-V��▼:↑���ĞUnC�nE+^H♀�gj��.��▲aZg�+9))�X∟♫0↔��▬↕��↔-��|�S�*Y�¶S�QK�r_�C�☼�^▼<�T��K
V���u>Vת�:Mj�Ӄm���I��▲�♀`*0♣8B♥�B!w�#-"§t.t8�∟0�♂e\�˂eA◄����E�↓↓�X�&⌂^�@/gFQ�p�3��3��-8����ec�▼~���?����§�?~�♂��a&����§}���k�Sa?���)\�矘w���►c6�,"���3�n���-�fl1_�8E��J�lX �����-�2��I�Uav�♫�♀���<◄‼�→�D�→�"�O4�◄�▲#\��p���l◄��◄gD_�]�p→)��dі�T�♥q%;i↨+e�(�U,�͈☺������↕�↕'R=�cs7G‼gV��(Vf�
_���`W��♠���.��<♀�W◄����p�}�§,��▼�����♥31�R�n3<���~sCЬ.�#�W/�4�XP.���ЬN'��4%W,�L���+Js=�(ɵ�◄�F�n�d��T�N↨�♂^�R�0�� §�♂����B��yO���Tnt�YS\����ZRj/>-7M�D��hZl↑II|Z�8}♀o⌂WobU��DoFg��Q�(�ne�i��♣ˋ▲�♦{�^���>;����zݞ�'���☼ܧr�{����smN��t������X<9�)-9▲ɑ��G:&��+²�♂;I↑����v�r����m=��Qkk�<��V,y���$��l�fwm/û�b~‼��.އ�lm��H��♫���X����↔?S⌂̕*�☺���A�dlǱS,�d5���q�v�:M��↓♂�☻j♣v��◄!�g�WbՊ�u��fύHE�♂�=�a�޴��u����R�T~�/P��→>|�P�[�pĢ�1��,��.��?�xr���������↔>
����]�◄��s5+�S`�#���H=+.R�:♠R[f��U�f�u���ϩd>����J斀qv♦↑♣�☺�Q⌂���▼X70+�F�g▼f�\♥�iI='ú☺◄vO<��Ǎ��o��♣�{΀3��2��H�Z,�z«]Q%�N�QHlGl"\�e�ݑbC�l_����'�{fa?GvV�'݈(�◄Q�♣E"�w$�f��♦��uv3�☺��
M7�z������g�|`P�/�����☼�[R♫v@'�0l��▲◄y{�▲�2���Z�)~�(�'������-݌�}���↓k�i�͘-qeK7c�>�-�▲���d�f�n���X���9�§צ����7�▼��hW.�.r�+K�ز�n�̊-I2�4t8♫Hr�$ɒ���!���|7.��m�l$�P�♥69��<�(6��w�������T♠s¸\�"�Xs��<�Ps�o�y]
↨k4ɑ6����\⢲�♥��♫Q�oO��;���T�=�)��8‼J�▼:�C♫o��K]%%�+��AA↓;[JJ
�=�Ci���%8'^ג�J���%�ܻw��.☻◄:Z�]K*��V�ص@�=�♥:�$��/���yPн�.[M��G��g�Յ�r�Q→,**���.�0��H�↕�(�l����������S�tw60���☺'̀8��(�♥.�
(☺�◄↨��Ȣ�>↓u¶qG↔F !��(2��8��qߝy�˼�s�ax@:�{oUu:�������:U]骺���|g�N��.P楽n�]♣���↨;r���G�Γg=�{►!�]�♂◄ `�▼C~�'�����
A��_箜�;��/ݾ�St��H�☻�o▬SU��☻�Y��↕0� Z◄�(@Q►����1��☺*�c�Eb-=▬ұꄈ
------WebKitFormBoundaryRd0FO6fKwoKf2ui6--
```

Comment: Maybe the below-linked one will help you. [how-to-read-formdata-in-nextjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66674834/how-to-read-formdata-in-nextjs)

Comment: Checking out the post you linked rn, thank you (Raviteja) in advance, even if I can not get it working from that.

Comment: Thank you for the link but I could not get a solution out of it.