# How to .blob() my image file in my Next.js project?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to use next.js APIs, but I'm having some trouble. I have a `<input type="file"/>` and a normal `<input type="text"/>` where I can select an image or paste an image's link. After submitting, based on whichever option I chose, I have the following if-statement:

```
if (typeof imageUrl == "object") {
      result = await fetch(`/api/imageProcessing`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: imageUrl,
      });
    } else {
      result = await fetch(
        `/api/imageProcessing?image=${encodeURIComponent(imageUrl)}`,
        {
          method: "GET",
        }
      );
    }
```

and the 'GET' method works, but the 'POST' method doesn't because I need to `.blob()` the image. the error Im getting is:

> 'body.blob() is not a function'

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { method, body, query } = req;

  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      const imageUrl = query.image;

      if (!imageUrl) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: "Missing image url parameter" });
      }

      const imageFile = await fetch(imageUrl).then((res) => res.blob());
      const result = await processing(imageFile);

      res.status(200).json({ message: "done", ...result });
      break;

    case "POST":
      if (body) {
        // const imageFile = await body.blob();
        const result = await processing(imageFile);

        res.status(200).json({ message: "done", ...result });
      } else {
        res
          .status(400)
          .json({ message: "Missing image file in the request body" });
      }
      break;

    default:
      res.status(405).json({ message: "Method Not Allowed" });
      break;
  }
}
```

I'm really lost on how to `.blob()` it since the function 'processing' depends on it. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62411430/post-multipart-form-data-to-serverless-next-js-api-running-on-vercel-now-sh)

Since your requirement involves handling both an image file from an `<input type="file"/>` and an image URL from an `<input type="text"/>`, and considering the issue you're facing with the `POST` method when trying to upload an image directly, I suggest using `multiparty`:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import multiparty from 'multiparty';

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false, // Disable the default body parser
  },
};

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, async (error, fields, files) => {
      if (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Form parsing error' });
        return;
      }
      const { path: imagePath } = files.image[0]; // Adjust based on your input's name attribute
      const imageBuffer = await fs.promises.readFile(imagePath);
      const result = await processing(imageBuffer); // Adjust your processing function to handle Buffer
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'Done', ...result });
    });
  } else {
    // Handle other methods or return an error
    res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST']);
    res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, it worked! thanks. Didn't know about those packages.